# Can I combine both AddSignIn() with AddProtectedWebApi() when using Microsoft.Indentity.Web for authentication?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, identity

I'm in the process of setting up a SPA client which calls to an Api service. Using the Microsoft Identity platform I have the Spa client set up in AzureAD to return the required Access Token.

On the Api side I've got basic app with a Home page then a seperate api controller.

I can protect the Api calls by using `services.AddProtectedWebApi(Configuration)` call and setting up the Cors Policy to allow requests from the location where the Spa is deployed.

What I would like to be able to do is have the user Sign In separately when using the Api service as this will have a few monitoring screens and Hangfire running to manage background tasks.

If I do this by adding 'services.AddSignIn(Configuration)' it must be overwriting the settings made in `services.AddProtectedWebApi(Configuration)` as the sign in works but the Api calls do not, and vice versa.

Is there a way to use both the `AddSignIn(...)` and `AddProtectedWebApi(...)`; perhaps through separate Authtenication Policy's...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just add this (to default authentication to your MVC controllers):

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "OpenIdConnect"; 
});
```

And this in your Api Controllers:

```cs
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
```

Or this (to default authentication to your API controllers):

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Bearer"; 
});
```

And this in your MVC Controllers:

```cs
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "OpenIdConnect")]
```

Comment: Thanks Alfredo; I’ll post my solution tomorrow. I ended up using a BaseApiController with the Authorise=“Bearer” attribute then registering the “OpenIdConnect” as a Fallback, rather than Default, Policy so everything was protected by default and I had to explicitly open any routes that are to be public.